# How to accept Decimal values in Foundation 6

Tags: html, input, numbers, decimal, zurb-foundation-6

I have a form field built in Foundation 6 but it does not allow for decimal input.

HTML

```
<input type="number" name="decimal_amount" max="10" placeholder="" required>
```

When I enter **8.5** I get this error:

**Please enter a valid value. The two nearest values are 8 and 9.**

**Here is the entire HTML block:**

```
    <head>
    <!-- Foundation CSS via CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.css">
    <!-- 1140px Grid styles for IE -->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <!-- The 1140px Grid - http://cssgrid.net/ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/1140.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!--css3-mediaqueries-js - http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ - Enables media queries in some unsupported browsers-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <!-- Foundation JavaScript via CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
          <label class="left">Ranking (scale 1-10, decimals allowed)
            <input type="number" name="decimal_amount" max="10" placeholder="" required>
          </label>
        </div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
```

Here is the error console
[image]

Comment: Are you using abide validation? Where exactly is the error coming from?

Comment: Not sure on the abide validation. How would I discover that? And the error is a pop-up from Foundation. Thanks for helping @Yass

Comment: Abide validation is one of the Foundation plugins, which you're probably not using (as you're not sure about it). Are you using custom jquery code for validation or are you relying on the built-in html5 functionality? Would it be possible to post more of the html content and any custom javascript you're using?

Comment: Ok. then I am not using abide as I have been use pure Foundation. Not even any custom javascript. I'll update the OQ with more HTML

Comment: I added the entire HTML container block @Yass

Comment: I've copied your code into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/8tn7x4mj/) and I'm not seeing the error message you're seeing.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? Also, it appears that you're referencing the Foundation library twice (once in the head and again at the bottom of the body)

Comment: I tried your fiddle and it does not render any of the errors I get including when I enter an 11 that is over the max.

Comment: Where should the Foundation lib go best? `<head>` or `<body>` ?

Comment: At the bottom of the body is fine. Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Make sure you reference jQuery before it's used. Remove the reference to foundation.min.js from the `head` as you've got a reference in the `body`.

Comment: I removed the Foundation lib from the <head> and I still cannot enter a decimal value.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue so I'm not sure what the problem is. The `max` attribute doesn't appear to work as expected in a fiddle. I've also tried it in a CodePen without any external libraries and it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really a question of HTML5. Add the `step="0.1"` to the input to describe the type of decimal precision. Here is an example to the 100th's.

```
<input type="number" name="decimal_amount" max="10" step="0.01" placeholder="" required>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-step

Comment: Excellent. Thank you @ChrisO. That did it for me.